# Star trek Borg origins

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-tos, borg

could the origin of the borg be tied in somehow (creatively) with the original series episode "The Lights of Zetar"? Were they 100% certain they destroyed them in the compression chamber or just drove them out into another time/space dimension?  It IS Star Trek after all with all the time warp travels and such.
 (just a seed of thought)

Comment: This is called Small-Universe Thinking.

Comment: Borg origins have not been explained in canon. Have you tried the post-Nemesis books though? There is a great trilogy 'Star Trek: Destiny' that you may find interesting.

Comment: I recall the lights being driven out by pressure, but I don't remember anything about them being thought 'destroyed.'  Memory Alpha's article indicates: "The aliens are successfully driven out of her body. ... The Zetarians did not further attack the Enterprise."

Comment: “just a seed of thought” — unfortunately, the button says “Ask question”, not “Plant seed of thought”.